# Windows Service: Managed Compatibility Mode does not support Edit and Continue

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, c#-4.0, windows-services

I have been assigned to work on a Windows Service project. I installed it in my machine using installer class (ProjectInstaller.cs). I want to debug the source code and sometimes need to make changes while it is in debug mode. I attached the process via Debug menu to debug the project which works fine but it throw an error while I am trying to edit or continue the source code:

**Managed Compatibility Mode does not support Edit and Continue**

I googled and tried tons of solutions but none of them worked for me, couple of them are as below:

- Unchecked the Use Managed Compatibility Mode from Tools -> Options
- Unchecked Managed Compatibility Mode from Debug -> Attach to Process
  -> Attached To -> Select...
- Checked the Managed (v4.6, V4.5, V4.0) from Debug -> Attach to
  Process -> Attached To -> Select...
- Played with Platform target in Project Build.
- Added *{351668CC-8477-4fbf-BFE3-5F1006E4DB1F}* field in my .csproj file

The error message varies depending on different solutions I implemented.

Below is the link I last time tried:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2013/10/16/switching-to-managed-compatibility-mode-in-visual-studio-2013/

I am guessing: the last one didn't work because I do not have an exe project for my service instead I have implemented ProjectInstaller.cs Class and manually installed it through command prompt.

Any suggestion/recommendation are welcomed.

Comment: Using Debug > Attach will *never* give you E+C, you'll have to stop trying.  Usually the best way to debug a service is to write the code so it can run it as a console mode app first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit and Continue requires many factors which are not obvious to users. Your case is simply not supported (mostly for attaching cases).

See [Supported Code Changes (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164927.aspx) in MSDN.  In particular:

> Edit and Continue is not available in the following debugging scenarios: [...]
>
> Debugging an application that has Attach to instead of running the application by choosing Start from the Debug menu.

Answer (score 5):

Unckeck Use Managed Compatibility Mode, It working for me! and you must Enable Edit and Continue in Debuging General [image]

Answer (score 2):

Attaching my process for each debug was a headache for me.

Just want to share a link that saved a lot of my time by writing a simple method and calling it in **Main()** method inside **Program.cs**.

This also gives me flexibility to edit and continue my code as simple as WinForm / Web Form. LOVE IT.

https://coding.abel.nu/2012/05/debugging-a-windows-service-project/

Answer (score 1):

I reset the VISUAL STUDIO settings and the problem is resolved
hope it helps [to Reset visual studio setting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Works for me! :)